# Git: gitk how to reset to origin/master

Tags: git, gitk

I use gitk to browse code.
I often right-click on a previous commit and `reset master branch to here`.
Then I compile and test the code.

If I close gitk now and restart it, it can no longer see previous commits.
Then I have to type in command line `git reset --hard origin/master`

Is there a way for gitk to always show the full commit history till origin/master?

Comment: Or what is a better way to go back and test code ?

Comment: I'm not sure about gitk, but if you are just going back in time to test old commits, the easiest way is to just `git checkout <commit hash>` and then `git checkout <current branch name>` to go back.

Comment: alright, seems git checkout is a better way. when do people use reset to a commit then?

Comment: Most common scenario is when you want to discard a commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of resetting your branch, just checkout the commit ID you mean to have as your HEAD

```
git checkout <commit-id>
```

That way you'll have a detached head and your working copy will be on that commit. When you think you're good, you can just get back to your previous branch:

```
git checkout <branch>
```

Comment: Not always. If you fiddled with the code on the detached head, git won't accept a simple `git checkout <branch>` and instead complains "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout" and aborts.